# Android studio find image with wild card at end to display

Tags: android

I'm trying to click through several full screen images and depending on what button I click, come up with a file name to display next.

For example A_UP0_LEFT2_B

would go to B_UP0_LEFT0_?

the syntax of my file names are currentscreen_xcoordinate_ycoordinate_destinationscreen

The question mark will be another letter and I'm wondering if there is a way for me to look through my drawables directory programatically if I have the string "B_UP0_LEFT0_" and find an image to display next, let's say it's "B_UP0_LEFT0_C.jpg"

short version: if I have a string "B_UP0_LEFT0_" and there is only one file with that string  but it also has a "C" at the very end of it, is there any way for me in android to use that string to find the full file from the drawable folder? ie. "R.drawable.B_UP0_LEFT0_C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the drawable names via this snippet:

```
Field[] drawableNames = R.drawable.class.getFields();
for (Field f : drawableNames) {
    try {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

from there I guess a `Regex` match or simple `startsWith()` or `contains()` will do the trick for you.

Also to find a drawable by its name using something like this:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: What would I import to use Field[]? I can't seem to find the information anywhere. This looks like it'll work, I'll keep you updated and accept if it works. thanks!

Comment: ctrl shift o doesn't help?

Comment: my pleasure :-)